# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

Tags: python-3.x, list, image

[My code--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THG9j.jpg)]

I am making a Qr code generator via GUI using the qrcode module in python, on the console it works perfectly but if i trie it on the gui via btn clicked method it gives me a weird error message about files not even in my Project. For Example : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkhkK.jpg) - Error Message
I am pretty new to python and never worked with GUI

Firstly I deleted the **init** file(Mistake) and then I looked over the internet over solutions that I didn't find.
There are Error Messages like ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

Comment: see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Assuming you know how to install packages using pip, just reinstall the package, seems like Pillow in this scenario.